# Can't find files inside volume mount directory

Tags: kubernetes

I have an mysql container I'm deploying through k8s in which I am mounting a directory which contains a script, once the pod is up and running the plan is to execute that script.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
spec:
   replicas: 1
   template:
      spec:
         volumes:
           - name: mysql-stuff
             hostPath:
                path: /home/myapp/scripts
                type: Directory
         containers:
           - name: mysql-db
             image: mysql:latest
             volueMounts:
               - name: mysql-stuff
                 mountPath: /scripts/
```

Once I have it up and running and run `kubectl exec -it mysql-db -- bin/sh` and `ls scripts` it returns nothing and the script that should be inside it is not there and I can't work out why.. For the sake of getting this working I have added no security context and am running the container as root. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: are you running your pod in a minikube cluster?

Comment: yeap, running in minikube

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are running your pod in a minikube cluster. Minikube itself is running in a VM , so the path mapping here implies the path of minikube VMs not your actual host.

However you can map your actual host path to the minikube path and then it will become accessible.

```
minikube mount /home/myapp/scripts:/home/myapp/scripts
```

See more here
https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/mount/